# Testing optional for nil and switching nil to 0

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am working on a simple app where I need to add two numbers entered in a text field together. I want to make it so that if on of the textfields doesn't have an entry in it, it will calculate as 0. What is the most efficient way to do this? Any help would be appreciated

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    //reveals label upon click of button
    myLabel1.hidden = false

    //textField constants
    let firstNum = Double(myTextField1.text!)
    let secondNum = Double(myTextField2.text!)


    let outputValue = Double(firstNum! + secondNum!)
    myLabel1.text = "Result: \(outputValue)"


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) (with a correction from [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397660/testing-optional-for-nil-and-switching-nil-to-0/35397682#comment58497966_35397682)):**

```
let firstNum = Double(myTextField1.text ?? "") ?? 0
let secondNum = Double(myTextField2.text ?? "") ?? 0
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an error about strings and ints. Your reply did encourage me to try this in other forms and I did get it to work...

Comment: let firstNum = Double(myTextField1.text!) ?? 0 and I had to alter the outpuValue, but now it seems to have broken my keyboard call, lol

Comment: This has problems.  A `?` must be followed by a member access, method call, or index.  I suggest `let firstNum = Double(myTextField1.text ?? "") ?? 0`.  This will handle both a nil field and one that doesn't convert to a double like "two".

Comment: @vacawama yup, realised that just as I did it, thx for correction.

Comment: @vacawama that worked. Thank you both. Now to read up on this to understand why it worked, lol

Comment: The `nil coalescing operator` is really useful. `a = b ?? c` is shorthand for `if b != nil { a = b! } else { a = c }`.  Using the ternary `?:` operator, it is shorthand for `a = (b != nil) ? b! : c`.